# how to make drop down menu in dashboard in splunk

Tags: xml, splunk

I have made a query for making dashboard In splunk. the search string shows the top 2 memory utilization.
I want to create a drop down menu for it.

my code is

```
<dashboard>
 <label>drop_Menu</label>
 <row>
  <table>
   <label>top 2 sneid</label>
   <input type="dropdown" token="SNEID" searchWhenChanged="true">
    <label>Select Device</label>
    <choice value="*">Any</choice>
    <default>Any</default>
    <populatingSearch fieldForValue="SNEID" fieldForLabel="SNEID">
    <![CDATA[source="CPU Sample4.csv" |top 2 SNEID showperc=f showcount=f|uniq]]>
    </populatingSearch>
   </input>
  </table>
 </row>
</dashboard>
```

it is not showing any result.
please help me to make drop down menu for queried items

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can have a custom dropdown in a dashboard. Although the XML is basically the same, I think you need to change the `dashboard` tag to `form`.

There are also some ways of simplifying advanced XML modification. You can take a look at the [Sideview Utils](http://sideviewapps.com/apps/sideview-utils/) project.